# How to structure Fragment identifiers in my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web, fragment-identifier

This is more of a best practices/ease of upkeep question.

I have several webpages where I would like to make browsing easier. So, to do that I am going to use Fragment identifiers (internal links). Here is an example of some of my HTML:

```
<article>
     <h1>Name of WebPage</h1>
          <h2>Section One</h2>
               Here is the content of my Section one.

          <h2>Section Two</h2>
               Here is the content of my Section two.

          <h2>Section Three</h2>
               Here is the content of my Section three.

          ....(may have additional h2 sections)
</article>
```

These webpages can be hard to navigate if there are dozens of h2 tags. I hope to use a side menu bar that utilizes Fragment Identifiers to link to 'Section One', 'Section Two', 'Section Three', etc.

Now, I need to convert this html code to use Fragment Identifiers, but before I go about changing this code, I wanted to get some additional thoughts on how I should do this.

I have a couple options:

1) Manual change the

```
<h2> NameOfH2 </h2>
```

to

```
<h2 id='NameOfH2'> NameOfH2 </h2>
```

Then, add the Fragment Identifier links in the side menu manually.

2) Manual change the

```
<h2> NameOfH2 </h2>
```

to

```
<h2 id='NameOfH2'> NameOfH2 </h2>
```

Then, use Javascript to build the side menu bar's Fragment Identifier links every time     the page loads.

I would like to use method 2, so that as I add more content to my pages, it will automatically show up in the side menu bar, but I wanted to see if there was any reason I should not do this.

Also, I have a ton of  tags to edit, and was wondering if you guys had any thoughts on how I should add the id's to the html. Right now, I am considering writing a program to go through each page and edit each  tag, but I wanted to see if a solution already exists out there.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This is a design question rather than a technical question suitable for SO. But on the technical side, you can assign `id` attributes to `article` elements; this matters especially if you style with `:target`. And of course you should generate the attributes and the internal table of content server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the internal links only working when JavaScript is enabled, you could just generate both the TOC and the fragment identifiers using JavaScript.

PPK has a script that does just that: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/toc.html

If you need it to work with JS turned off, you could generate both the TOC and IDs server side.